# Loop through specific worksheets and Clearcontents not working

Tags: excel, for-loop, spreadsheet, vba

I've tried to use a loop to clear the contents of some worksheets, but couldn't get it to clear out the data in the cells.

This is the (working) static code I've started with:

```
Set oWS2 = Sheets("WEBSHOP-NL")
Set oWS3 = Sheets("WEBSHOP-FR")
Set oWS4 = Sheets("WEBSHOP-EN")
```

~~>

```
  oWS2.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
  oWS3.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
  oWS4.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
```

This is what I've already got: The messagebox outputs oWS2 ~> oWS3 ~> oWS4
But... It's not clearing the contents.

'LoopThroughSheets

```
Dim Shts As Variant
Dim Sht As Variant

Shts = Array("oWS2", "oWS3", "oWS4")

For Each Sht In Shts    'Loop Sheets Code goes here:
    Sht.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    MsgBox "Sht = " & Sht, vbInformation
Next Sht
```

What am I overlooking here? Thanks when responding.

Comment: You should remove the quotes from your array as they are variable names not sheet names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is an array of strings, not worksheet objects. So you'll have to specify the worksheet you are interested in according to it's name. Much like you did in your original code `Set oWS2 = Sheets("WEBSHOP-NL")` using the Sheets object.

```
Dim Shts As Variant
Dim Sht As Variant

Shts = Array("WEBSHOP-NL", "WEBSHOP-FR", "WEBSHOP-EN")

For Each Sht In Shts    'Loop Sheets Code goes here:
    Sheets(Sht).UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    MsgBox "Sht = " & Sht, vbInformation
Next Sht
```

Alternatively you could stick with your existing code, but remove the quotes around the variables in your array, but this seems like it's cumbersome to set all these variables, stick them into an array, then iterate the array:

```
Set oWS2 = Sheets("WEBSHOP-NL")
Set oWS3 = Sheets("WEBSHOP-FR")
Set oWS4 = Sheets("WEBSHOP-EN")

'LoopThroughSheets

Dim Shts As Variant
Dim Sht As Variant

Shts = Array(oWS2, oWS3, oWS4)

For Each Sht In Shts    'Loop Sheets Code goes here:
    Sht.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    MsgBox "Sht = " & Sht, vbInformation
Next Sht
```